# How to select row from tabel and than input to new table looping for count select before in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How to select row from table and than input to new table looping for count select before in php mysql,

in case sophing chart.

in localhost this code can work find. but while i'm trying to online why just first record in WHERE clause can insert to Orders table and dlete like as.

```
     $sid = session_id();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id_session='$sid'");

// get  orders number
$id_orders=mysql_insert_id();

while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $item = $r['item'];
    $size = $r['size'];
    $kateg_bahan = $r['kateg_bahan'];
    $warna = $r['warna'];
    $jumlah = $r['jumlah'];
    $harga = $r['harga'];
    $sub_total = $r['sub_total'];
    $id_keranjang =$r['id_keranjang'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders(id_orders, id_kustomer, nama_kustomer, alamat, telpon, email, tgl_order, jam_order, jasa, id_kota, item, size, kateg_bahan, warna, jumlah, harga, sub_total) 
             VALUES('$id_orders', '$id_kustomer', '$nama','$alamat','$telpon','$email','$tgl_skrg','$jam_skrg', '$jasa', '$id_kota','$item', '$size', '$kateg_bahan', '$warna', '$jumlah', '$harga', '$sub_total')");


    }
$delsql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keranjang WHERE id_session='$sid'");   
while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($delsql)) {
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM keranjang WHERE id_keranjang = '$r[id_keranjang]'");
}
```

Comment: Fortunately for us, the value of `$harga` will never be anything like `"foo',0); DROP TABLE orders; -- "`, or we might have a real problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, but what is obvious is that you unnecessarily hit your database with queries.

IMHO all your code can be boiled down to two sql queries that might look like this

```php
$sid = session_id();
// get  orders number
$id_orders = mysql_insert_id();

$sql = "
INSERT INTO orders
       (id_orders, id_kustomer, nama_kustomer, 
        alamat, telpon, email, tgl_order, 
        jam_order, jasa, id_kota, 
        item, size, kateg_bahan, warna, jumlah, harga, sub_total) 
SELECT '$id_orders', '$id_kustomer', '$nama',
       '$alamat','$telpon','$email','$tgl_skrg',
       '$jam_skrg', '$jasa', '$id_kota', 
       item, size, kateg_bahan, warna, jumlah, harga, sub_total
  FROM cart 
 WHERE id_session = '$sid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error()); //TODO better error handling
}

$sql = "DELETE FROM keranjang WHERE id_session = '$sid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error()); //TODO better error handling
}
```

**On a side note:** you're using deprecated extension `mysql_*` and your code is vulnerable to sql-injections. Learn and use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: I was try this code, in page result eror like:

1062: Duplicate entry '54' for key 'PRIMARY'

and just one record can insert in table order.

I was tray in mysql ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 , why stil show error like that

Comment: @AjiNgestu Without seeing other relevant parts of code, table schema and information about what data is already in it unfortunately it's almost impossible to answer your follow up question intelligently. But if you feel that the original answer was useful please, consider to **[upvote/accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The existing code is nearly indecipherable. The "big idea" of what it's trying to accomplish seems to be obscured by a lot of unnecessary manipulation, and whole boatload of unnecessary SQL executions.

We infer, since the `mysql_insert_id()` function returns the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the last row that was inserted. and that this called once, before the loop, and that the value retrieved is inserted as a column value in the following inserts... we infer that `id_orders` is a foreign key to some other table, into which a row was just inserted.

(The column name `id_orders` is an odd choice of a column in the `orders` table, for a column which is not a unique identifer of a row. If that is a unique identifier, then we are going expect a lot of the insert statements to fail with a duplicate key exception.

And given that there is no check whether the execution of an INSERT statement was successful or not, are we to assume that a failure of an INSERT is fine, and we can just continue processing? (That strikes me as a bit odd, unless the plan really is to put our pinky to the corner of our mouth, Dr. Evil style, and say "I just assume it all going to plan. What?")

I just can't fathom a reason this needs to be done in a loop, processing each row, row by agonizing row, when the same end result could be accomplished much more efficiently with two relatively simple SQL statements.

What it appears that the agonizing code in the question is attempting to do, could be accomplished much more succinctly with something like this:

```
$sql_text = "INSERT INTO orders
                  ( id_orders
                  , id_kustomer
                  , nama_kustomer
                  , alamat
                  , telpon
                  , email
                  , tgl_order
                  , jam_order
                  , jasa
                  , id_kota
                  , item
                  , size
                  , kateg_bahan
                  , warna
                  , jumlah
                  , harga
                  , sub_total)
             SELECT NULL AS id_orders"
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($id_kustomer)."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($nama       )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($alamat     )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($telpon     )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($email      )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($tgl_skrg   )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($jam_skrg   )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($jasa       )."'
                  , '".mysql_real_escape_string($id_kota    )."'
                  , c.item
                  , c.size
                  , c.kateg_bahan
                  , c.warna
                  , c.jumlah
                  , c.harga
                  , c.sub_total
               FROM cart c
              WHERE c.id_session='".mysql_real_escape_string(session_id()."'";
//echo "sql_text=".$sql_text; // for debugging
mysql_query($sql_text) or die(mysql_error());

$sql_text = "DELETE FROM keranjang k
              WHERE k.id_session='".mysql_real_escape_string(session_id()."'";
//echo "sql_text=".$sql_text; // for debugging
mysql_query($sql_text) or die(mysql_error());
```

One could argue that "die" may not be the most appropriate action, if we happen to be procesing against InnoDB tables, perhaps we are in the context of a TRANSACTION, and a ROLLBACK might be appropriate. But it seems like we should make at least some effort to determine whether a statement threw and exception or not.

All of the variables are now wrapped in calls to the `mysql_real_escape_string` function. If the contents of these variables has already been sanitized (previously in the code), then we should omit the call to `mysql_real_escape_string`.  (I generally use a prefix on a variable name that contains the "sanitized" copy of another variable, to make it clear whether a string being included in SQL text has already been escaped. But that's really more about following a consistent pattern that helps make "wrong code look wrong")

---

Does anyone NOT understand what "**deprecated**" means? New code should NOT be using **mysql_** functions, but should instead be using either **mysqli** or **PDO**.

Comment: I was try this code, in page result eror like:

1062: Duplicate entry '54' for key 'PRIMARY'

and just one record can insert in table order.

I was tray in mysql ALTER TABLE orders AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 , why stil show error like that

Comment: It's likely that `id_orders` columns is the PRIMARY KEY of the table. If that's the case, then the code in my answer is broken, in the same way the code in the original code is broken. To fix the code, and allow the `id_orders` value be derived from the AUTO_INCREMENT, assign a NULL value to the column in the INSERT. Assigning it the return value from `mysql_insert_id()` is wrong. We would use that function to find the value that was assigned to the column, AFTER an insert. Example above is modified. (We don't see where the variables are set; example follows pattern of OP code.)

Comment: If you are asking why the error is shown, rather than being hidden, it's because return from the query is being checked, unlike the original code. When errors occur, we generally want to know about them, rather than having the statement fail silently.